# Confusion about why the toral subalgebra can be both semisimple and nilpotent

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am self studying Humphrey's Lie algebra text and I am trying to understand the proof that the centralizer the maximal toral subalgebra is in fact equal to the subalgebra.

SO by definition, all elements of the toral subalgebra is semisimple, but then during part of the proof, we even prove that the centralizer is nilpotent:

[image]

[image]

But this is where I got confused, because since the centralizer contains $H$ and elements of $H$ are by definition semisimple, this would imply that every elements in $H$ is both semisimple and nilpotent. But the only elements where can be both semisimple and nilpotent is $0$. So this implies that $H=0$ which makes no sense. So what is going on?

Comment: The elements are semisimple and not nilpotent as elements of the larger Lie algebra. They act as $0$ on the Cartan subalgebra and are happily semisimple and nilpotent there (as you say $0$ is both). To say it more carefully, $\operatorname{ad}x$ is $0$ on $C$ and thus $x$ is ad-nilpotent on $C$ even though it is not ad-nilpotent on $L$. This distinguishes toral subalgebras from other kinds of nilpotent subalgebras like the set of upper triangular matrices inside $\mathfrak{sl}_n$

Comment: Just to add a striking special case to @Callum's comment, if you take any semisimple element $x$, then the one dimensional Lie subalgebra it generates is nilpotent.